# Firefox equivalent setting for Chromium's --disable-font-subpixel-positioning on Linux

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I have a Windows-centric website which I'd like to make work on Firefox on Linux. It uses web fonts and several weird parameters to display complex text, but on Linux it's misaligned everywhere.

I just found out that, in Chromium, I had the same behavior. However, when I add option `--disable-font-subpixel-positioning` when running Chromium, everything gets magically fixed!

However, I need it to work on Firefox. But I could not find an equivalent setting. I tried `about:config` and toggling all `gfx.font_rendering.*` settings, as well as all `gfx.text.*` settings, including the very promising `gfx.text.subpixel-position.force-disabled`, but it didn't change anything. I tried changing and restarting Firefox, but I couldn't see *any* differences. As if these options had no effect whatsoever.

Is there a way to disable font subpixel positioning on Firefox?

The images below show the different renderings in part of a page which contains a summary (unfortunately the website requires a login so I cannot just put a link to it). The leftmost is Firefox, the middle one is Chromium with default settings, and the rightmost is Chromium with `--disable-font-subpixel-positioning`.

*Note that the font size differences and height are due to me not being able to capture the exact same height on both browsers; the website automatically adjusts the text to fill the screen, so I cannot easily force both to maintain the same height.*

[image: Default Firefox rendering] [image: Default Chromium rendering] [image: Chromium with disabled font subpixel rendering]

FWIW, I'm using Firefox 104 and Chromium 103.